# Sql service could not be started

Tags: sql-server-2005, service

Please advise me on this issue:

I have one default SQL instance in SQL Server 2005(sp 3 x64 bits) called instanceA
Then I installed another 2 instances call instanceB and C.

After that I restore master.bak from production server to this instanceB. The SQL services for  this instance could not be started at all since then. If I turned off the default instance services, instanceB can be started. This is because both of the instances are pointing to the same 'model.mdf' file in 'MSSQL.1' folder. Hence both instances could not be started simultaneously.

I believe that in production server, the model path is configured to the default folder 'MSSQL.1' .Is there anyway to change the path to 'MSSQL.8' that belongs to instanceB upon installation so that both instances A and B could be started together?

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you restore master from a different instance?

Comment: because I need to create an environment that same as Production server. Thats why I restore a master that is back up from Production.